# Why do I need to include a helper twice in order to access it in the mailer and its view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In order to get my mailer and the view to render correctly, I have to do the following:

```
include ::KamilHelper
add_template_helper(KamilHelper)
```

since i use the method `do_it()` both here:

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::BAse
  def run_it
    do_it()
  end
end
```

and in its corresponding view:

```
<%= do_it() %>.
```

Otherwise, I get:

```
undefined method `do_it' for #<Notifier:0x00000102b24af0>
```

for the view or the mailer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing `include ::KamilHelper` in a controller? If so, this includes the methods from the helper into the current class (e.g. the controller), but methods from a controller are not available in a view. `add_template_helper` makes those methods available to templates rendered *from* the current controller (by calling `include ::KamilHelper` inside the modules that are available to the view templates).